# JSON_EXTRACT() Query returns NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

I have a question regarding the MySQL `json_extract` function.

I've created a table called `PacJSON` by copying data from the `PAC` table and adding a new JSON column called `hc`. I've also populated this `hc` column with JSON data.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db`.`PacJSON`;
CREATE TABLE PacJSON AS SELECT * FROM PAC;
ALTER TABLE PacJSON ADD COLUMN hc JSON DEFAULT NULL;
UPDATE `db`.`PacJSON`
SET `hc`='[{"estado":"1"},{"descripcion":"name1"},{"estudio": "name2"}, {"url":"name3"},{"idpaciente":"11"},{"idmedico":"6"},{"fecha_hc":"2019-05-2"}]'
WHERE idUsuario=11;
```

The issue I'm encountering is that the following query returns a null value instead of 6:

```
SELECT idUsuario, PacJSON.hc, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(hc, '$."idmedico"')) AS "idmedico"
FROM PacJson;
```

Can someone please point out what I might be doing wrong? I expected the query to return 6, but it's returning null instead.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `hc` value contains an array of objects, so you need to use a path which reflects that i.e. `$[*].idmedico`. Note that double quotes should *not* be used in the path.

```
SELECT idUsuario,
       hc,
       JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(hc ,'$[*].idmedico')) AS idmedico
FROM PacJSON
```

Output:

```
["6"]
```

Note that because `hc` is an array, `JSON_EXTRACT` returns one too. If you know there's only one `idmedico` value in the JSON, you can use `JSON_EXTRACT` again on that result to get the actual numeric value:

```
SELECT idUsuario,
       hc,
       JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(hc ,'$[*].idmedico'), '$[0]')) AS idmedico
FROM PacJSON
```

Output:

```
6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wQcUo1fiZnLvueGZsk3Utj/0)